# skip mysql password in bash script when password is empty

Tags: mysql, bash, passwords

I have a bash file `db_reset`

```
drop database foo;
create database foo;
```

And I am trying to run this script:

```
prompt> mysql -uroot -p < db_reset
```

the password is requested every time

```
prompt> mysql -uroot -p < db_reset
Enter password:
```

And I want to skip this step. Password is empty. I've tried with solutions like

```
prompt> mysql -uroot -p"" < db_reset
Enter password:
```

but the result is always the same. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to supply a password, just omit (leave off) the **`-p`** option

```
:~$ mysql -u root
```

N.B. A blank password is *not* secure. If this was my database, there's no way that there would be root account, or any account, without a password or other secure authentication mechanism. (MySQL shouldn't even allow connections without authentication.)

Comment: Uh, thanks. I have been thought that with empty password, `-p` was still required in bash commands. thanks.